# Why is (int)'\xff' != 0xff but (int)'\x7f' == 0x7f?

Tags: c++, byte

Consider this code :

```
typedef union
{
    int integer_;
    char mem_[4];
} MemoryView;

int main()
{
    MemoryView mv;
    mv.integer_ = (int)'\xff';
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \xff\xff\xff\xff

    mv.integer_ = 0xff;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \xff\x00\x00\x00

    // now i try with a value less than 0x80
    mv.integer_ = (int)'\x7f'
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \x7f\x00\x00\x00


    mv.integer_ = 0x7f;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \x7f\x00\x00\x00

    // now i try with 0x80
    mv.integer_ = (int)'\x80'
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \x80\xff\xff\xff

    mv.integer_ = 0x80;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        std::cout << mv.mem_[i]; // output is \x80\x00\x00\x00

}
```

I tested it with both GCC4.6 and MSVC2010 and results was same.
When I try with values less than 0x80 output is correct but with values bigger than 0x80,
left three bytes are '\xff'.

CPU : Intel 'core 2 Duo'
Endianness : little
OS : Ubuntu 12.04LTS (64bit), Windows 7(64 bit)

Comment: Compile it as C, and they will be the same. `\xff` doesn't fit into a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `'\xff'` is `char`. `char` is a signed integral type on a lot of platforms, so the value of `'\xff` is negative (`-1` rather than `255`). When you convert (cast) that to an `int` (also signed), you get an int with the same, negative, value.

Anything strictly less than `0x80` will be positive, and you'll get a positive out of the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

It's *implementation-specific* whether type `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*.

---

Assigning a variable of type `char` the value of `0xFF` might either yield `255` (if type is really *unsigned*) or `-1` (if type is really *signed*) in most implementations (where the number of bits in `char` is `8`).

Values less, or equal to, `0x7F` (`127`) will fit in both an *unsigned char*  and a *signed char* which explains why you are getting the result you are describing.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cerr << "unsigned char: "
            << +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min ()
            << " to "
            << +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max ()
            << ", 0xFF = "
            << +static_cast<unsigned char> ('\xFF')
            << std::endl;

  std::cerr << "  signed char: "
            << +std::numeric_limits<signed char>::min ()
            << " to "
            << +std::numeric_limits<signed char>::max ()
            << ", 0xFF = "
            << +static_cast<signed char> ('\xFF')
            << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>typical output</sup>

```
unsigned char: 0 to 255, 0xFF = 255
  signed char: -128 to 127, 0xFF = -1
```

---

To circumvent the problem you are experiencing explicitly declare your variable as either *signed* or *unsigned*, in this case casting your value into a `unsigned char` will be sufficient:

```
mv.integer_ = static_cast<unsigned char> ('\xFF'); /* 255, NOT -1 */
```

---

<sup>**side note:**</sup>
<sup>you are invoking *undefined behaviour* when reading a member of a *union* that is not the last member you wrote to. the standard doesn't specify what will be going on in this case. sure, under most implementations it will work as expected. accessing `union.mem_[0]` will most probably yield the first byte of `union.integer_`, but this is not guarenteed.</sup>

Comment: What does the unary plus `+` do?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it will cast the operand to an integer (preventing it from being printed as a `char`), `+'A'` will yield it's numeral representation, which normally is *65*. `+ch` can be seen as a short form of `static_cast<int> (ch)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `'\xff'` is a signed char (default for `char` is signed in many architectures, but not always) - when converted to an integer, it is sign-extended, to make it 32-bit (in this case) `int`.

In binary arithmetic, nearly all negative representations use the highest bit to indicate "this is negative" and some sort of "inverse" logic to represent the value. The most common is to use "two's complement", where there is no "negative zero". In this form, all ones is `-1`, and the "most negative number" is a 1 followed by a lot of zeros, so 0x80 in 8 bits is -128, 0x8000 in 16 bits is -32768, and 0x80000000 is -2147 million (and some more digits).

A solution, in this case, would be to use `static_cast<unsigned char>('\xff')`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `0xff` stored in a signed 8 bit char is `-1`. Whether a `char` without `signed`or `unsigned` specifier is signed or unsigned depends on the compiler and/or platform and in this case it seems to be.

Cast to an int, it keeps the value -1, which stored in a 32 bit signed int is `0xffffffff`.

`0x7f` on the other hand stored in an 8 bit signed char is `127`, which cast to a 32 bit int is `0x0000007f`.